# How to access a string path param in a in API Gateway for AWS

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

So I have something like

```
my/path/123
```

And this works fine.

However, when I try with a string "asdf"

```
my/path/"asdf"
```

I get this

```
{"message": "Could not parse request body into json: Unexpected character (\'%\' (code 37)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, \'true\', \'false\' or \'null\')\n at [Source: [B@420db2ef; line: 2, column: 13]"}
```

And if I try w/o quotes (so my/path/asdf) I get this:

```
{"message": "Could not parse request body into json: Unrecognized token \'asdf\': was expecting (\'true\', \'false\' or \'null\')\n at [Source: [B@7fba20c8; line: 2, column: 17]"}
```

And if I try `https://7mdamwt4jg.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod/%22asdf%22`

(%22 is stands for double quotes)

I get this:

```
{"message": "Could not parse request body into json: Unexpected character (\'%\' (code 37)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, \'true\', \'false\' or \'null\')\n at [Source: [B@7f4f2919; line: 2, column: 13]"}
```

What else can I try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a body mapping template in integration request and get path param like below,

```
{
 "PathName" : "$input.params('PathName')"
}
```

Where 'PathName' is the name of your path param.

Say your path name is UserId then you can get params inside Lambda function like an event.UserId. Please see below screenshots to get into body mapping template,

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This error indicates that your Lambda function cannot parse request string into json. The problem is most likely to be in your mapping template. See working example here https://gist.github.com/rpgreen/5cd3d5c872781335a5d3